# Android webview html compliance?

Tags: android, html, webview

I have a webview that displays some HTML i am generating at runtime.  This html works in chrome and IE, but when I try to load it into the webview, it tells me "Web page not available"  I'm using basic HTML elements:

```
<body bgcolor="01517f">
    <table>
        <font color="ffffff" size="4">
            <p>
                <a href="http://www.gim.net/Customized/Uploads/Screenshot532011-33538-PM.jpg">
                    <img src="http://www.gim.net/Customized/Uploads/Screenshot532011-33538-PM.jpg" width="160" height="240" align="right">
                </a>
                Message body
            </p>
            <table width="95%" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" >
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <b>
                            <font size="3" color="ffffff">
                                parent1
                            </font>
                        </b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <p align="right">
                            <font size="2" color="ffffff">
                                This will be the date string
                            </font>
                        </p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan ="2">
                        <p align="left">
                            <font size="3" color="ffffff">
                                Blah blah
                            </font>
                        </p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <hr noshade size="1" />
        </font>
    </table>
</body>
```

For some reason, if I remove the nested table, it seems to display fine.  Is there something non-standard about how I am formatting my HTML that would make it not work with the android webview?

EDIT:
After thorough elimination testing, I have discovered that the offending error is from the "width='95%'" attribute of the second table.  If I change it to a set pixel width( ex: width="160px") it works.  What I need this width for is forcing those elements in that table to be below the image, while still occupying most of the width of the page, not knowing how large my page is going to be, because I do not know how large the screen I might be working with is.

Should I just figure out the screen size, and manually set the pixel width that way, or is there some simpler way I can force a break between the image aligned to the right, and the table that follows below it?

Comment: You missing the tbody tag and don't use font. Use css to style it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was the way that the Android webview attempts to access the HTML data when you call `loadData` on it.  I noticed that when I got the error the "web address" it was trying to access was basically my HTML code as a URL, replacing non standard characters with their http friendly versions (%20 for the space character for example).  So I simply replaced the % sign in my "width='95%'" with the code for the % sign ( %25 ) and it works perfectly now.  No need for CSS or anything like that

Answer (score 2):

1. The `font`-Tags are obsolete
2. Color and Text size should be set
   using CSS
3. If you want to align of your Text to
   be left, you can simply do this
   using `text-align` in
   CSS
4. The `align`-Attribute is deprecated, too.
   Use CSS to do that.
5. `img`-Tags should always have a
   `alt`-Attribute, unless they are
   part of the Layout.
6. Both `width` and `height`-Attributes are
   deprecated, use CSS to do that.
   Also, don't use a number without any
   unit. If you want 140 Pixel the
   write `140px` (Unless you want 0,
   thats just 0 without any unit).
7. I'm not sure if this is due to this
   being a snipped, but a HTML-Page
   starts with an `<html>`-Tag and has
   a `<head>`-Tag before the
   `<body>`-Tag.
8. A HTML-Page should always have a
   Doctype-Declaration.

If you're not sure if your HTML is valid, go [Validate it](http://validator.w3.org/).

Also, i don't get what you use the first table for. It does simply nothing. It doesn't even have a TableRow or some TableData in it. It's not valid and it's not good for anything. Cut it out.

Comment: Is there any way I can fix this without using CSS? I feel like that would be way overcomplicating things for displaying some simple formatted text.  Not to mention I dont know the first thing about CSS or how i would even use it in android

Comment: Also if font is obsolete, that doesn't explain why it works without the nested table, as there is a font tag in the beginning

Comment: 1. You should use CSS if you want to format something and stick to the standards. That's just it. 2. That doesn't mean that the `font`-Tag doesn't work anymore. But the common way is to use CSS and some newer Browsers might now (or in the future) remove support for this tag.

Comment: Im not trying to create an entire page, just format some text and an image with HTML, and CSS is not a valid solution if it is not supported by android

Comment: CSS is sure supported by android. The Android browser is Webkit based, like Chrome. You said, that it works when you take out the first `table`-tag. So take it out, it's not doing anything.